# How to hide whole line of text with words

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to follow the format for when I was hiding pets in my game but it didn't turn out the same.

[image]

How would I hide a line like this? I get how to hide a radio button.

I've tried something similar to what I did for radio buttons but it didn't turn out the same. how do I give those lines of text/other things a name so I can hide then till a condition is met?

This is my current Javascript:

```
var Silver = document.getElementById('Silver');
var Gold = document.getElementById('Gold');
var Diamond = document.getElementById('Diamond');



function checkUnlockOre() {
    if (Mininglv >= 10) {
        Silver.style.visibility = 'visible'
    } else {
        Silver.style.visibility = 'hidden'
    }
     if (Mininglv >= 20) {
        Gold.style.visibility = 'visible'
    } else {
         Gold.style.visibility = 'hidden'
    }
    if (Mininglv >= 30) {
         Diamond.style.visibility = 'visible'
    } else {
        Diamond.style.visibility = 'hidden'
    }

}

checkUnlockOre()
```

HTML code:

```
<div>
    <br />
    Bronze: <span id="Bronze">0</span>
    <br />
    Silver: <span id="Silver">0</span>
    <br />
    Gold: <span id="Gold">0</span>
    <br />
    Diamond: <span id="Diamond">0</span>
</div>
```

I expect the ores to be not visible until a condition is met, but my actual outcome they are all visible and I can't figure out how to hide those lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add parent span and hide full part based on condition.

```js
var Silver = document.getElementById('Silver');
var Gold = document.getElementById('Gold');
var Diamond = document.getElementById('Diamond');

var SilverParent = document.getElementById('SilverParent');
var GoldParent = document.getElementById('GoldParent');
var DiamondParent = document.getElementById('DiamondParent');

var Mininglv = 5;
function checkUnlockOre() {
    if (Mininglv >= 10) {
        SilverParent.style.visibility = 'visible'
    } else {
        SilverParent.style.visibility = 'hidden'
    }
     if (Mininglv >= 20) {
        GoldParent.style.visibility = 'visible'
    } else {
         GoldParent.style.visibility = 'hidden'
    }
    if (Mininglv >= 30) {
         DiamondParent.style.visibility = 'visible'
    } else {
        DiamondParent.style.visibility = 'hidden'
    }

}

checkUnlockOre()
```

```html
<br />
  <span id="BronzeParent">
  Bronze: <span id="Bronze">0</span>
   <br />
  </span>
  
  <span id="SilverParent">
  Silver: <span id="Silver">0</span>
  <br />
  </span>
  
  <span id="GoldParent">
  Gold: <span id="Gold">0</span>
  <br />
  </span>
  
  <span id="DiamondParent">
  Diamond: <span id="Diamond">0</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: oh I see. so you put a <span id> before a line of text to tie to to a function that makes a lot of sense thanks